# Почему date не используется? python

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, aiogram

Вот код:

```
from aiogram import types
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import State, StatesGroup
from misc import dp
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage

total = 0
date = 0
kb_date_credit = ['3', '14', '30']

class CreditQuestion(StatesGroup):
    waiting_user_name = State()
    waiting_old_size = State()
    waiting_date_size = State()
    waiting_total_size = State()

@dp.message_handler(commands=["bank"], state="*")
async def bank_step_1(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer('Ты в банке "acyncio", тут можно взять микро кредит под 300% ой, под маленькие проценты')
    await message.answer('Как вас зовут?')
    await CreditQuestion.waiting_user_name.set()

@dp.message_handler(state=CreditQuestion.waiting_user_name, content_types=types.ContentTypes.TEXT)
async def bank_step_2(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.update_data(name=message.text.lower())

    await message.answer('Введите ваш возраст:')
    await CreditQuestion.waiting_old_size.set()

@dp.message_handler(state=CreditQuestion.waiting_old_size, content_types=types.ContentTypes.TEXT)
async def bank_step_3(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    if int(message.text) < 18:
        await message.answer('18+! Возвращаем обратно!')
        state.finish()
    else: 
        await state.update_data(old=message.text.lower())
        await message.answer('Следующий шаг!')
        keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        for name in kb_date_credit:
            keyboard.add(name)
        await message.answer('Насколько дней взять кредит?', reply_markup=keyboard)
        await CreditQuestion.waiting_date_size.set()


@dp.message_handler(state=CreditQuestion.waiting_date_size, content_types=types.ContentTypes.TEXT)
async def bank_step_4(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    if message.text not in kb_date_credit:
        await message.answer('Используету клавиатуру!')
    else:
        
        if message.text == '3':
            date = 3
        elif message.text == '14':
            date = 14
        elif message.text == '30':
            date = 3
        await message.answer('Следующий шаг', reply_markup=types.ReplyKeyboardRemove())
        await message.answer('Введите сумму пополнения, только цифры')
        await CreditQuestion.waiting_total_size.set()


@dp.message_handler(state=CreditQuestion.waiting_total_size, content_types=types.ContentTypes.TEXT) 
async def bank_step_5(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    try: 
        user_data = await state.get_data()
        int(message.text) == total
        await message.answer('Все данные сохранены!')
        await message.answer(f'Ваше имя: {user_data["name"]}, ваш возвраст: {user_data["old"]}, через {date} дней, вы получите {total * (date * 1.2)}')

    except:
        await message.answer('Обязательно цифру')
        return
```

Именно здесь ошибка:

```
@dp.message_handler(state=CreditQuestion.waiting_date_size, content_types=types.ContentTypes.TEXT)
async def bank_step_4(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    if message.text not in kb_date_credit:
        await message.answer('Используету клавиатуру!')
    else:
        
        if message.text == '3':
            date = 3
        elif message.text == '14':
            date = 14
        elif message.text == '30':
            date = 3
        await message.answer('Следующий шаг', reply_markup=types.ReplyKeyboardRemove())
        await message.answer('Введите сумму пополнения, только цифры')
        await CreditQuestion.waiting_total_size.set()
```

Почему то date не видит в

```
await message.answer(f'Ваше имя: {user_data["name"]}, ваш возвраст: {user_data["old"]}, через {date} дней, вы получите {total * (date * 1.2)}')
```

и выдает:
Ваше имя: никита, ваш возвраст: 18, через 0 дней

Comment: Потому что глобальная переменная `date` и локальная переменная `date` никак не связаны друг с другом. Если у вас стоит задача изменять глобальную переменную, то используйте `global data`

Answer (score 0):

Раз вы храните данные в `state.data`, то и используйте его:

```
@dp.message_handler(state=CreditQuestion.waiting_date_size, content_types=types.ContentTypes.TEXT)
async def bank_step_4(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    if message.text not in kb_date_credit:
        await message.answer('Используйте клавиатуру!')
    else:
        
        if message.text == '3':
            date = 3
        elif message.text == '14':
            date = 14
        elif message.text == '30':
            date = 3

        # Сохраняем значение
        await state.update_data(date=date)

        await message.answer('Следующий шаг', reply_markup=types.ReplyKeyboardRemove())
        await message.answer('Введите сумму пополнения, только цифры')
        await CreditQuestion.waiting_total_size.set()

@dp.message_handler(state=CreditQuestion.waiting_total_size, content_types=types.ContentTypes.TEXT) 
async def bank_step_5(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    try: 
        user_data = await state.get_data()
        int(message.text) == total
        await message.answer('Все данные сохранены!')

        # Вставляем правильное значение
        await message.answer(f'Ваше имя: {user_data["name"]}, ваш возраст: {user_data["old"]}, через {user_data["date"]} дней, вы получите {total * (user_data["date"] * 1.2)}')

    except:
        await message.answer('Обязательно цифру')
        return
```